# How Structure can be mapped with section attribute in a c program?

Tags: c, memory-mapped-files, sections

It is just a random thought about the structures in a c program.

In C program `__attribute__` provide a feature to specify special attributes when making a declaration.

section - Where a particular variable or a function can be placed at a particular address with the help of "section"

For example for a variable to be defined with attribute it can be done like this

`int g1 __attribute__((section (".vector"))) = 100;`

For a function to be defined with attribute it can be done like this

```
int some_function(void) __attribute__((section(".vector")));
   int some_function(void)
   {
   int local_variabale1 = 100;
    return local_variable1;

   }
```

so from above examples it is possible to put the section `.vector` at a particular address in which I specify the address in linked scripts.

Will there be a chance for structure in C to put the structure in section?

Suppose if this is my `structure program` in c

```
struct database
    {
    int employee_number;
    string name;
    int phone_number;
    };
```

If it is possible how can it be done?

Comment: C/C++ is not a thing. C and C++ approach problems in dramatically different ways. If C++ is not a concern here, omit  it.

Answer (score 3):

> Will there be a chance for structure in C to put the structure in section?

The definition of a structure doesn't exist anywhere in memory at runtime -- it's only used during compilation. As such, it doesn't make sense to give it a section.

If you're declaring an instance of that structure (e.g. `struct database DB`), that's a variable, and that can be placed in a section. The structure itself isn't a variable, though.

Comment: Well Thank  you, instance of structure can be placed at defined sections...Like this ```struct database db __attribute__ ((section (".vector"))); ```